# What reference do I need in order to create a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: c#, dll, powerpoint

I am having a problem getting the following code to work:

```
Presentation ppt = new Presentation();
```

How do I know which dll to find and reference?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Microsoft Office installed, follow these steps:

1. Open the `Project` menu  > Add Reference > `COM` tab > `Microsoft PowerPoint xx.x Object Library`.

   [image: Add Reference]
2. Add the following `using` statement at the top of your file:

   ```
   using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
   ```
3. Make sure that the `Embed Interop Type` property of the reference is set to true:

   [image: Embed Interop Type]
4. Obviously, you'll need Microsoft Office to be installed on the client machine as well.